# Grunt install node_modules locally

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I have a Gruntfile to install some npm and make other function.

The problem is that: the download of npm works fine but download node_modules globally in

```
/User/my_user/node_modules
```

I'd want that the gruntfile download nom locally inside my project dynamically without specify path.

this is a part of my grunt file:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        shell: {
            install: {
                options: {
                    stdout: true,
                    stderr: true
                },
                command: [
                    "npm install grunt-contrib-sass",
                    "npm install node-sass",
                    "npm install grunt-contrib-less",
                    "npm install less",
                    "npm install grunt-contrib-watch",
                    "npm install grunt-contrib-clean",
                    "npm install grunt-contrib-copy",
                    "npm install grunt-csso",
                    "npm install grunt-deployments"
                ].join("&&")
            },
            install_test: {
                options: {
                    stdout: true,
                    stderr: true
                },
                command: [
                    "sudo npm install -g phantomjs",
                    "npm install -g casperjs",
                    "mkdir app/Test/Frontend",
                    "sudo chmod -R 777 app/Test/Frontend"
                ].join("&&")
            },
        }
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-less");
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-watch");
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-clean");
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-copy");
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-shell");
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-csso");
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-rsync");

    grunt.registerTask("install", [
        "shell:cake_tmp",
        "shell:install",
        "shell:install_test"
    ]);
};
```

and after I do this:

```
sudo npm install grunt
sudo npm install grunt-shell
grunt install
```

return me error that it doesn't find modules because aren't locally but globally..

How can I solve?

Thanks

Comment: Make sure your shell commands are are runned in your CWD.

Comment: I don't understand why you are putting these things in your Gruntfile. It looks like they should be in your `package.json` and then installed all together with `npm install`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats a very crude way of doing the job. Ideally, all of that should go in to `package.json` in your root folder. put this in you `package.json` after making necessary changes if any and execute `npm install` it will install the packages locally and `preinstall` hook will install global packages beforing executing install.

```
{
    "name": "appname",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "dependencies": {},
    "devDependencies": {
        "grunt": "~0.4.1",
        "grunt-contrib-sass": "*",
        "node-sass": "*",
        "less": "*",
        "grunt-concurrent": "*",
        "grunt-contrib-clean": "*",
        "grunt-contrib-watch": "*",
        "grunt-contrib-less": "*",
        "grunt-contrib-copy": "*",
        "grunt-shell": "*",
        "grunt-csso": "*",
        "grunt-deployments": "*"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": ">=0.8.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "test": "grunt test",
        "preinstall": "sudo npm install -g phantomjs && npm install -g casperjs"
    }
  }
```

npm gives hooks called preinstall,install,postinstall etc., use them to do `-g` installs.

follow this [LINK](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-scripts.html) for more info

Other tasks you can include in your `Gruntfile.js` as `shell` targets

Comment: `npm global` installs are currently not possible from package.json, using `preinstall` hook is a workaround.